# How can I enable mod_proxy_http

Tags: xampp

How can enable and load mod_proxy_http?

I have XAMPP, and I want to enable mod_proxy_http

I can see the module XAMPP/apache/modules/mod_proxy_http.so but I don't see any commanted module directives to uncomment in file XAMPP/apahce/conf/httpd.comf

I have restarted the server and I see the module has not loaded through phpinfo()

How can enable and load mod_proxy_http?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have lines similar to this in your httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
```

Which enable the modules in question. With the module enabled, you'll want to add configuration on how you're wanting to use mod_proxy. There's example configurations located [here.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) Be sure to also follow the recommendations in the [security area](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#access).

```
<Proxy *>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 192.168.0
</Proxy>
```

If you're configuring a reverse proxy, it's recommended to implement the paths in the relevant virtual host code blocK.

```
ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

Comment: How do I enable the module?

Comment: Updated my answer to include that.

Comment: And restart Apache to get it all to work.

Comment: @Andrew Ty. I have made the changes you indicate. However, of all the modules you list, if I enable mod_proxy_balancer Apache won;t start and I get this error "[Thu Apr 18 12:20:39.270326 2013] [proxy_balancer:emerg] [pid 12188:tid 252] AH01177: Failed to lookup provider 'shm' for 'slotmem': is mod_slotmem_shm loaded??
[Thu Apr 18 12:20:39.270326 2013] [:emerg] [pid 12188:tid 252] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting" But if I disable this only one module Apache starts. Can I do w/o this module?

Comment: Definitely, I just grepped mod_proxy from my httpd.conf to show you the various modules. Infact, you can leave all but `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` disabled for the purposes you've shown thus far..

Comment: @IberoMedia  add this line to httpd.conf   :   LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so